# What translucent material can I use to cover the bulbs at the top of a medicine cabinet?

Tags: lighting, cabinets

I am restoring a medicine cabinet that has light bulbs on the top but no covering.  Should I try to cover that area with glass (I'd like something frosted or opaque) or is there some type of plastic or other material that can be used?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.  I added some detail to the title to make it more specific and easier to find in a search (the vast majority of the questions here have very specific titles).  Back to your question: what size, wattage and type of bulbs do you have now, and (if they're incandescent) would you be willing to use energy-efficient bulbs instead?

Comment: A photo would help.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use frosted glass, though acrylic is easier to work with and lighter weight. You can cut it with a saw, it's effectively "shatterproof," and the edges aren't sharp like glass.

[image: Frosted Acrylic]

Frosted acrylic sheets are available at many DIY "big box" stores, and online. You may know this acrylic material by the brand name Plexiglas.

Acrylic sheet is also available in a variety of patterns and textures, as shown on [one manufacturer's website](http://www.plaskolite.com/ProductCatalog/OPTIX-Acrylic-Lighting-Panels).

One easy way to go might be to find a replacement diffuser panel for an overhead fluorescent light fixture. and cut it to fit your application.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the type of the lightbulb and the distance of the cover.

- With incandescent you should use glass if the cover is close, and plastic if it is 10 cm away (for a 40W lightbulb).
- With CFL or LED bulbs you can use plastic close and even *paper* a bit further away, especially if the cover is not fully closed, and the hot air can leave easily.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like these [image]

[image]

Comment: Link only answers don't work well, especially when the links go bad.

Comment: why it is  so badd

Comment: Because when either of those sites removes the link, your answer is as good as directing someone to look [here](http://www.mancha.demon.co.uk/rotafle_lamp_02x.jpg). See also: [Why are some answers deleted](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: oh ok i will edit it